# Assigning a number by ID by date

Tags: python, pandas

This is an example of my CSV data:

> [1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mOvb.png

How to assign an attempt number for each ID by date (incrementing)? For example, in the pictured piece should be two attempts.
TYSM!

Comment: As you can see by the to sultions the question is not clear. Could you please be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#preparing data
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[3,3,3,3,3,3], 'date': pd.date_range('2021.5.11','2021.5.13', 6)})
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.date

#solution
df['attampt'] = df.groupby(['id', 'date'])['id'].transform(lambda x: range(1, len(list(x))+1))
df
```

Output:

```
    id  date    attampt
0   3   2021-05-11  1
1   3   2021-05-11  2
2   3   2021-05-11  3
3   3   2021-05-12  1
4   3   2021-05-12  2
5   3   2021-05-13  1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an ID by date, one option is to `.shift()` the column you want to count the changes by 1 and compare this to the original. You have to fill the one existing `Nan` with `.fillna()`. If the shift is not equal to the original, than you get a `Ture` and this can be counted by `.cumsum()`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Test Date':['1/10/2017', '1/10/2017', '1/10/2017', '11/4/2016', '11/4/2016']})
df['Attempt'] = (df['Test Date'] != df['Test Date'].shift(1)).fillna(True).cumsum()
>>> df
   Test Date  Attempt
0  1/10/2017        1
1  1/10/2017        1
2  1/10/2017        1
3  11/4/2016        2
4  11/4/2016        2
```

Comment: This is not a good answer. Because the solution should work for every id.